# RISC-V: Implementing SLLI, SRLI and SRAI

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv

In RISC-V  instruction set manual, the shift Immediate instructions:

1. SLLI (Shift Left Logical Immediate).
2. SRLI (Shift Right Logical Immediate).
3. SRAI (Shift Right Arithmetic Immediate).

It is mentioned in the manual

> Shifts by a constant are encoded as a specialization of the I-type
>   format. The operand to be shifted is in rs1, and the shift amount is
>   encoded in the lower 5 bits of the I-immediate field. The right shift
>   type is encoded in a high bit of the I-immediate. SLLI is a logical
>   left shift (zeros are shifted into the lower bits); SRLI is a logical
>   right shift (zeros are shifted into the upper bits); and SRAI is an
>   arithmetic right shift (the original sign bit is copied into the
>   vacated upper bits).

When it is said that

> shift amount is encoded in the lower 5 bits of the I-immediate
>   field.

How it will be encoded exactly?

Another thing does that mean it will take multiple clock cycles to shift as specified in the lower 5 bits of the I-immediate? or can this be done in one clock cycle?
[image]

Comment: For your second question: The ISA doesn't specify how many cycles an instruction takes. This depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the answer directly in the [RISC-V](https://riscv.org/specifications/) specifications.

[image: Encoding of SARI, SLLI and SRLI]

```
 imm[11:5]    imm[4:0]   rs1    func3   rd   opcode    inst
------------------------------------------------------------
 0000000      shamt      rs1    001     rd   0010011   SLLI
 0000000      shamt      rs1    101     rd   0010011   SRLI
 0100000      shamt      rs1    101     rd   0010011   SRAI
```

As for the latency, the ISA only deals with *architectures* not *micro-architectures*.
That means that two RISC-V conforming CPUs can execute a shift in a different number of clock cycles.

Comment: It seems like the OP is mostly asking how shamt is encoded.  So the answer is: as a 5-bit binary integer.

Comment: Yes I know that ISA does not commit to any microarchitecture but I was asking from a microarchitectures point of view, can this shift be done in one clock cycle? since it is 5 bit encoding this means a maximum of 32 shifts, this seems like a big compromise between doing it as a combinational shifting hardware or one shift per cycle. Right?

Comment: I believe 32 (0-31) shifts comes from the fact that registers are 32-bit wide, doing a 32-bit shift equals to doing a 0-bit shift, 33-bit shift equal 1-bit shift and so on. I could be done in one cycle, but even Intel on the latest top-notch processors can't do that.

Comment: Yes, a shift can be done in one cycle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter).

Comment: A barrel shifter will need 5 stages to perform the shift based on 5 bits describing the shift number. This means the shift would take much longer to propagate the answer than almost any other ISA instruction. So you could do this in a single cycle but that causes you to have a slow clock frequency to ensure it would be completed. Alternatively you could stall the CPU for multiple cycles when a shift occurs so that it has chance to complete without restricting the speed of other instructions. It becomes a design trade off.

Comment: @PhilWright: each barrel shifter stage is 1 or a few gate delays, not 1 clock cycle!  Real world high performance CPUs have single-cycle latency variable-count shifters.  For example, modern mainstream Intel and AMD (see `shlx` in https://uops.info/), and some can clock themselves up to ~5GHz without overclocking.  `add` also has a dependency chain of carry propagation that's hard to handle; even carry-lookahead / [carry-select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-select_adder) adders still have multiple gate delays.

Comment: @PhilWright: What's actually slow is a multiply, where all those partial products have to be accumulated, which is hard even with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadda_multiplier to avoid needing to work out the full carry propagation at each partial step.  That's why for example on Intel CPUs, most scalar integer ops are 1 cycle latency, but integer multiple is 3 cycles.  (Along with `popcnt`, and bit-scan for first or last set bit).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options for doing a shift implementation. The least hardware is to a bit at a time, so 32 cycles for a 32 bit shift. A barrel shifter is much more hardware intensive but can shift 32 bits in about the same time as a 32 add. Note that the add needs to propagate carry bits while the 32 bit barrel shifter needs 5  stages (2^^5 = 32). One trick is to break the shift between stages in a multistage pipelined processor. Do an optional bit reverse, 3 barrel shift stages in the EX (Execute) cycle, then the last 2 barrel shift stages in the MEM (Memory/Load/Store) cycle with an optional bit reverse. Latency is now two cycles for the shift. Early complete logic can be added so two or three bit shifts complete in one cycle. Byte shift logic can also be added to do 8x bit shifts in one cycle. Note the bit reversal allows all shifts SLL,SRL,SRA to be done in one direction, shift right, saving some logic. So, many options in the hardware design, add more hardware logic and shifts can be done very fast!